# Using single-member structs as the member itself

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use structs to expose a typesafish interface, like:

```
class IFoo
{
  virtual HRESULT bar(struct _BAR * arg) = 0;
}
```

Behind the scene, each implementation of this interface defines its own struct:

```
struct _BAR { Baz baz };
```

I currently call many allocation functions this way:

```
HRESULT allocate(Baz ** baz);
_BAR * bar;
ret = allocate( (Baz **) &bar );
```

Is it possible to call them with a more type-safe cast, like `static_cast`, by adding data in the `struct _BAR` definition?

Comment: Heads-up: you have UB here through the pointer cast, but also from the conflicting definitions of `_BAR` which violate ODR. I think you're knee-deep in a solution which won't pan out.

Comment: each implementation defines its own struct? `_BAR` has to be always the same type, and you cannot define the same type more than once

Comment: Alright, I went with a distinct solution. Is this question useful or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @Quentin, this is a violation of ODR (one definition rule). I am not sure what your purpose is, but you can consider 2 things to meet your need. One is using a template. The other one is to use `void *`. but I am just guessing and hope that helps.

Comment: Ah I see. I can perhaps use templates, although I am not sure how to solve this. I could make the structures public, and have them have a single `void *` member to ensure "type safetyness" on the caller side.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an empty structure as a base:

```
// For base interface
struct _BAR {};

// For an implementation
struct Baz : BAR { ... };
```

In this case static_cast would do, and it will be legal C++